# ValueError: arrays must all be same length in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have tried different possibilities to find out the reason for error. But didn't found reason for error. Could please help me what went wrong in my code.

```
def businesslogic(dirs, userpath):
    data = {}
    for fold in dirs:
        files = os.listdir(fold)
        if 'Test.txt' in files:
            with open(os.path.join(fold,'Test.txt'),'r') as te:
                lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in te.readlines()]
        else:
            print('Test.txt does not exist')

        rows = [value.split(';')[0] for value in lines]
        data[fold] = [value.split(';')[1] for value in lines]

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)---->>>ValueError: arrays must all be same length

    df.index = rows
    cols = list(df.columns.values)

    req = df.loc[['TubeType', 'Digits']]
    req = req[cols].astype(int)
```

Comment: One or move lists of the data dictionary has a different length. They all must have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

Since your folders don't necessarily have the same number of files, you get this error. With your format, each folder is represented as a column. And the first file of all folders will be in the first row, the second files in the second row, etc... The problem arises when you have different number of files in two different folders. A specific folder will need 10 rows (because it contains 10 files) while annother will only need 8. Pandas considers this as an error of input.

If you want to have all the information in the same line, here is what you could do :

```
# Example a data dict where folders contain different number of files
data= {'folder1' : ['file1', 'file2'], 'folder2' : ['file3'] }

pd.DataFrame({x : [[y for y in data[x]]] for x in data})
```

---

Output :

```
          folder1  folder2
0  [file1, file2]  [file3]
```